# can I create a symlink from an ec2 disk to S3 bucket?

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, msmq

Is it possible to create a symlink from a file on the local disk of a Windows machine in ec2 so that it is actually stored in an S3 bucket?

MSMQ wants to write our queue to a local disk and this does not seem to be configurable, which means the queue would be lost if the machine went down. We would like to have the queue written somewhere that could be recovered if the machine died.

Is this an option? If not are there any other options?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done easily if the EC2 instance is running Linux, using [Fuse Over Amazon](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon). While there is a Windows version of FUSE named [Dokan](http://dokan-dev.net/en/about/), it will probably be quite a bit of work to get Fuse for Amazon working with it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Microsoft would want you to implement an [MSMQ cluster](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753575%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) to achieve your goal.

Alternatively, if you can get the bucket mounted as a drive letter, which seems to be available from various vendors, you could try creating a directory symbolic link.  I'm not so familiar with the layout of where MSMQ stores queue data, but something like this should work, if you're running Vista or above:

```
mklink /d C:\MSMQ\Queues H:\MSMQQueues
```

Assuming that MSMQ is looking for data in `C:\MSMQ\Queues`, and you want the data to be stored on `H:\MSMQQueues`.  Of course, MSMQ might be checking for this trick if it thinks it has a good reason to always write to local storage.